# How to combine two rails scopes containing lambda that has SQL queries?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

My objective is to somehow combine two scopes together which when count the results it would give me the desired number I am looking for. To start off, my first scope is:

```
scope :validation_status_pending, lambda {
    where(%{
      EXISTS (
        SELECT NULL
          FROM assigned_roles
          JOIN roles ON assigned_roles.role_id = roles.id
         WHERE assigned_roles.user_id = #{quoted_table_name}.id
           AND roles.validation_required
           AND NOT EXISTS (
              SELECT NULL
                FROM user_validations
               WHERE user_validations.assigned_role_id = assigned_roles.id) )
          })
  }
```

and my second scope:

```
 scope :new_registration_validation_status_pending, lambda {
    where(%{
      EXISTS (
        SELECT NULL
          FROM assigned_roles
          JOIN roles ON assigned_roles.role_id = roles.id
         WHERE assigned_roles.user_id = #{quoted_table_name}.id
           AND roles.validation_required
           AND #{quoted_table_name}.identity_quiz_passed = true
           AND NOT EXISTS (
              SELECT NULL
                FROM user_validations
                JOIN validation_templates ON validation_templates.id = user_validations.validation_template_id  AND validation_templates.notary_form = true
                WHERE user_validations.assigned_role_id = assigned_roles.id
                AND user_validations.validation_template_id IS NOT NULL))
          }).and.validation_status_pending
  }
```

When I try to count the number of records in the first scope like this:

```
User.where(registration_status: "pending").validation_status_pending.count
```

it will give me 27 pending records.

and when I try to count the number of records in the second scope like this:

```
User.where(registration_status: "pending").new_registration_validation_status_pending.count
```

It will give me 149 pending records.

For clarity of where these scopes are being used is through a method that used for filtering these values:

```
def self.validation_status(status)
    case status.to_sym
    when :not_required
      self.validation_status_not_required
    when :pending
      return self.validation_status_pending unless MyProject.features.new_registration.enabled?
      self.new_registration_validation_status_pending
    when :complete
      self.validation_status_complete
    else
      raise ArgumentError.exception "Valid Validation Statuses: #{UserValidationRules::VALIDATION_STATUSES.keys}"
    end
  end
```

What I **ultimately** want to do is combine these two scopes so that I can get the total of 176 (27 + 149).

Do you have any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

you need to construct an "OR" condition. Does this work?

```rb
MyModel.validation_status_pending.or(MyModel.validation_status(status))
```

Comment: Hi @Les Nightingill. I appended .or(self.validation_status(:pending)) to the end of "where"clause of validation_status_pending scope and the count shows 150. Is that how it should be done?

Comment: (I have edited my answer, `self` should not have been in there). No @Pouya I think it should be as I have shown (with my edit)